# OSPF на CentOS и Cisco не видят друг друга

Tags: centos, cisco, ospf

Имеется Cisco 2901, а также тачка на CentOS 7.
Появилась задача поднять динамическую маршрутизацию, выбрав протокол OSPF.
На Cisco благополучно он был поднят:

```
router ospf 1
network 10.0.10.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
network 10.0.13.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
network 10.0.17.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
neighbor 10.0.17.243
```

На CentOS были попытки поднять OSPF используя frr, конфиг OSPF следующий:

```
router ospf
network 10.0.17.0/24 are 0
network 192.168.99.0/29 area 0
neighbor 10.0.17.1
```

Однако сходимости сетей я не получил, увы.
Если поднимать CentOS <-> Centos, то все работает, но вот с Cisco <-> CentOS беда.
P.S.
SELINUX отключен
firewalld отключен
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
Картинкой прилагаю схему сети

[image: Сеть]

Comment: Дебажить пробовали на циско? Если да - что видите, какие ошибки? Если нет - пробовали запускать tshark на centos? Из первого что приходит в голову - это не согласованные тайминги или router id или тип neighbor.

Comment: А вообще hello туда и обратно ходят? В смысле видны они на интерфейсе центоси?

Comment: Как  можно проверить, ходят ли hello?

Answer (score 1):

на Quagga, а значит и на FRR тоже, должен работать такой вариант фрагмента конфигурации:

```
    router ospf
     redistribute connected route-map ospf-route
     network 10.0.17.0/24    area 0.0.0.0
     network 192.168.99.0/29 area 0.0.0.0
```

Обязательно нужно прописать **redistribute** как указано в примере.
Такая конфигурация успешно работает в реальной сети.
Для того чтобы проверить, что происходит в сегменте, можно использовать tcpdump:

```
    tcpdump -nvi any proto ospf
```

Чтобы проверить, какие маршруты пришли по ospf, используйте команду

```
    ip r
```

Рекомендую использовать следующую документацию:

https://www.nongnu.org/quagga/docs/docs-multi/OSPFv2.html#OSPFv2

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/frrouting/latest/frrouting.pdf